# Is it possible to obtain the path of the script using argparse?

Tags: python, command-line

I would like to know how to get the path where the script is stored with argparse, if possible, because if I run the script from another path (I have the path of the script in the %PATH% variable) it uses by default the relative path.

I know that I can obtain it using:

`import sys
sys.argv[0]`

but I would like to know if it is possible to acess it directly from the argparse module.

Thanks
Edit: I have my reply and I am satisfied. 
To explain better the question: I have a script called mdv.py that I use to transform markdown files into html. I would like to call it from any location in my computer. 
The script is in:
c:\Python27\markdown

in this path there are other files and a folder templates that I use to generate my HTML (a default stylesheet and files for header, body and footer).

These files are in:
C:\Python\27\markdown\markdown\templates

When I call the script from a non standard path, for example c:\dropbox\public it looks in c:\dropbox\public\templates for these files and not in c:\python27\markdown\templates where they are saved.

Ihope to have better explained. Sorry I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: `argparse` uses `sys.argv` too. Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for the [`prog` parameter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#prog); you can interpolate `sys.argv[0]` into your help strings with `%(prog)s`.

The value for `prog` can be set when creating the `ArgumentParser()` instance; it is the first parameter:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('some_other_name')
```

and can be retrieved with the `.prog` attribute:

```
print(parser.prog)  # prints "some_other_name"
```

*However*, `argparse`calls `os.path.basename()` on this name, and does **not** store the directory of the program anywhere.

Comment: Ok, what I really need is the path, hence I use sys.argv, but thanks for exaustive reply.