# How do you get the name of the program using argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using `argparse` to parse command line arguments. While going through the documentation for [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) I could only see a provision to use a different program name.

I want to be able to use the default program name without having to import `sys`. There is nothing in `argparse`, as far as I can see, that will return the program name.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = parser.parse_args()

print(dir(args))
```

And here's the output:

`['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_args', '_get_kwargs']`

Is there any other way of retrieving the program name without having to import the `sys` module?

Comment: Why don't you want to import sys in this case? If you wanted, you could just import argv. `from sys import argv`.

Comment: Was I wrong to assume that argparse is meant to be a module that is a wrapper over sys.argv[]? Since argparse parses all the command line arguments, should it not have had the program name as well for cleaner code? Imho, it looks rather odd when sys.argv[0] suddenly butts into the code when it's argparse everywhere else.

Comment: `argparse` imports `sys` as `_sys`.  So in theory you could use: `argparse._sys.argv[0]`.  Note also that `argparse` gets the command line strings (that it parses) from `_sys.argv[1:]`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17406225/1959808

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`ArgumentParser` instances have a `prog` attribute which I think is what you want.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
print('parser.prog: {}'.format(parser.prog))
```

I discovered this by reading the module's source code in [`Lib/argparse.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/argparse.py)—specifically looking at the `class ArgumentParser` [definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/argparse.py#L1672). Since the attribute's name doesn't start with an underscore character, I assume it's public.

***Update***

I see that, nowadays at least, that the `prog` attribute of `ArgumentParser` instance *is* (or has been since this question was asked) documented in both [Python 2's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects) and [Python 3's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects).

So, yes, it's definitely public, and in both versions, if it is not supplied as a keyword argument when creating the `ArgumentParser`, it defaults to `prog = _os.path.basename(_sys.argv[0])` (where `_os` and `_sys` are private `argparse` module attributes that correspond to their non-underscore-prefixed counterparts. Note that because of the use of `os.basename()`, this will only be the script's filename, not the complete path to it that *may* (it's OS dependent) have been in `sys.argv[0]`.

Answer (score 12):

Of course the correct way would be:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.argv[0]
    scripts/script.py
```

But let's assume for a moment you have a good reason that prevents you to `import sys` but allows you to `import argparse`.

[martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) has done a wonderful job discovering `prog`, let's try it:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> print parser.prog
    script.py
```

As noted by [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj), this only has the filename and not the full path like `sys.argv[0]` because the module [`argparse.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/71cb8f605f77/Lib/argparse.py) is using `prog = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])`.

But `argparse` must use `sys`, so it needs to be accessible in `argparse` namespace. Let's check it:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> print argparse.__dict__
    { ..., '_sys': <module 'sys' (built-in)>, ... }
```

Here it is! Let's try to use `_sys`:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> print argparse._sys.argv[0]
    scripts/script.py
```

You are using `sys`! Of course, but I haven't imported it, only `argparse`, that was the question!

Of course this has a number of contraindications:

- You should not use variables prefixed by `_` or `__` of other namespaces, they are used [internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python).
- You should not rely on imports of other modules, they may change.
- You should not rely on undocumented api, they may change.

#### tl;dr

This was fun, but just stick to `import sys` until `argparse` releases an api to access `sys.argv[0]`.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! I accepted @martineau's answer, though, because it directly answers my question.

Answer (score 8):

**`%(prog)` from inside `argparse` help texts**

This is a common use case when you want to give an example of how to use the command within the help itself.

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Do something cool. My name is: %(prog)s",
    epilog="""
This is how you do it:

    %(prog)s yourarg
""",
    formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter
)
parser.add_argument('somearg', help='also works here: %(prog)s')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then:

```
./main.py -h
```

gives:

```
usage: main.py [-h] somearg

Do something cool. My name is: main.py

positional arguments:
  somearg     also works here: main.py

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

This is how you do it:

    main.py yourarg
```

One advantage over `sys.argv[0]` is that the message stays unchanged no matter where you call it from:

```
cd ..
./mydir/main.py
```

Documented at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prog

> Note that the program name, whether determined from `sys.argv[0]` or from the `prog=` argument, is available to help messages using the `%(prog)s` format specifier.

Tested on Python 3.5.2.